# Prove whether the limit exists where $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, $f(x,y)=\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^3+y^3}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove whether the limit exists where $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^4+y^4}{x^3+y^3}$.

After doing polar coordination i get the next expression $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}r\frac{\cos^4x+\sin^4x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}$ I thought this one should be equal to $0$.

But i seems that the limitation above does no exists, How do i prove that one then?

Comment: You can choose to approach $(0, 0)$ along the line $x = -y$ to see that the limit does not exist on that line. This corresponds to the case when $\sin^3\theta + \cos^3\theta = 0$.

Comment: Why not just put $y=0$ and take the limit of $x$ and vice-versa?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh, because that's just one way to evaluate the limit (i.e., along the line $\,y=0\,$) . If the limit exists it **must** exist no matter how we approach the origin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in your limit if

$$\sin x=-\cos x\iff \tan x=-1\iff x=-\frac\pi4+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;\;?$$

This gives us the idea to put $\,y=-x \;$ and see what happens when $\,x\to 0\;$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^3+y^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^4}{x^3-x^3}$$

Since the function isn't *even* defined on $\,y=-x\,$ the limit cannot exist (as it **must** exist no matter how we approach the origin!)

Comment: ...but the numerator is also $0$ at the origin? So the limit may be finite and exist at that point as in e.g. the sinc function.

Comment: We don't care what happens to some function at the point where the variable(s) are going...in fact, by definition, we **must** not care. The point here is that the function isn't defined at all in the whole line $\,y=-x\,$ and thus cannot approach the origin along this line and thus the wanted limit, *by definition*, cannot exist.

Comment: Ok fair enough... :)

Comment: (+1) Just found this: http://www.sinclair.edu/centers/mathlab/pub/findyourcourse/worksheets/Calculus/LimitsOfFunctionsOfTwoVariables.pdf, it's a shame though because the limit is the same from any other line of approach in the whole domain!! :( lolz

Comment: Indeed so @GrahamHesketh

Comment: @DonAntonio What happen if we exclude that path from domain?

Answer (score 0):

more easy way is $y=ax$,then $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^4+y^4}{x^3+y^3}=x\dfrac{1+a^4}{1+a^3}$, so the answer is $0$

Comment: ...and what happens if $\,a=-1\,$ ?!

Comment: but it is not allowed $a=-1$ according to $f(x.y)$

Comment: I don't understand what you say, @chenbai: the definition of $\,f\,$ doesn't mention any $\,a\,$, it is **you** who defined it, and by definition of the limit it *must* exist no matter how $\,(x,y)\to(0,0)\,$ , and one way it is $\,y=-x\,$ , and the function isn't defined here, so the limit cannot exist.

Comment: what I was taught this function can't allow y=-x in anyway. so I think I can exclude this case. If I can't do it, I do learn a new idea. pls confirm me.( I saw your answer). thanks.

Comment: And you were taught right, and thus the function cannot allow $\;(x,y)\;$ to approach $\,(0,0)\,$ over **any** path want, and thus the limit cannot exist. Yes, this is basically my argument  in my answer. And no, you can *not* exclude that case, or any other case, when trying to calculate the limit.

Comment: thanks. now I understand when I calculate the limit I have to care all cases. I am happy to know that and thanks a lot.